# Yacc "rule useless due to conflicts"

Tags: yacc

i need some help with yacc. 
i'm working on a infix/postfix translator, the infix to postfix part was really easy but i'm having some issue with the postfix to infix translation.
here's an example on what i was going to do (just to translate an easy ab+c- or an abc+-)

```
exp: num {printf("+ ");} exp '+' 
   | num {printf("- ");} exp '-'
   | exp {printf("+ ");} num '+' 
   | exp {printf("- ");} num '-'    
   |/* empty*/
   ;

num: number {printf("%d ", $1);}
   ;
```

obiously it doesn't work because i'm asking an action (with the printfs) before the actual body so, while compiling, I get many

warning: rule useless in parser due to conflict

the problem is that the printfs are exactly where I need them (or my output wont be an infix expression). is there a way to keep the print actions right there and let yacc identify which one it needs to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, no there isn't. The problem is that to resolve what you've got, yacc would have to have an unbounded amount of lookahead. This is… problematic given that yacc is a fairly simple-minded tool, so instead it takes a (bad) guess and throws out some of your rules with a warning. You need to change your grammar so yacc can decide what to do with a token with only a very small amount of lookahead (a single token IIRC). The usual way to do this is to attach the interpretations of the values to the tokens and either use a post-action or, more practically, build a tree which you traverse as a separate step (doing print out of an infix expression from its syntax tree is trivial).

Note that when you've got warnings coming out of yacc, that typically means that your grammar is wrong and that the resulting parser will do very unexpected things. Refine it until you get *no* warnings from that stage at all. That is, treat grammar warnings as errors; anything else and you'll be sorry.

Comment: And yacc being a “fairly simple-minded tool” is a good thing in my eyes. It means that you can use it predictably; over-complex tools cause more trouble, much more!